# How to xpath to a value regardless of whether it exists in a list or not

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to access the values of Thing and Foo with a single xpath line. The xpath below can select both value nodes as I need.

`//*[contains(name(),"value")]`
However, the output is

```
<values><li>Thing</li></values>
<value>Foo</value>
```

The XML I'm using can be seen below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Defs>
    <something1>
        <values>
            <li>Thing</li>
        </values>
    </something1>
    <something2>
        <value>Foo</value>
    </something2>
    <something3>
        <other>Var</other>
    </something3>
</Defs>
```

The xpath above can select both "value" nodes, however, it also selects the list of Thing. Is there a way to expand on the xpath to allow for the selection of both Thing and Foo? [Note:The names Thing and Foo are entirely placeholders, many different values can take their place, but all values are words]

I don't want to have Var in the output however.

My intended output is hopefully

```
<li>Thing</li>
<value>Foo</value>
```

I'm not sure what XPath standard this utilises, from what I was able to find the 1.0 standard is the most likely candidate. For additional context, I am trying to create an XML patching mod for the game Rimworld, but I thought that context may not be entirely relevant to my initial question write-up.

Comment: Does `/*[contains(name(),"value")]//text()` get you what you want? That will include some newline text nodes as well, along with both `Thing1` and `Thing2`.

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Comment: @larsk Thanks for the comment, unfortunately, I am passing the result of this xpath to another function as a local path so it can search through parents so it requires the node format `<something>ThingN</something>`, it doesn't have to be "value" but for this issue, I have `<something><li>Thing1</li></something>`. Using `/*[contains(name(), "value")]//text()` gives that function the text ThingN where it expects the partial xPath.

Comment: You say "many different values can take their place". There's no way of answering a question like this without knowing more about exactly what your selection criteria are, and exactly what the possible contents of the XML are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Defs>
    <something1>
        <values>
            <li>Thing</li>
        </values>
    </something1>
    <something2>
        <value>Foo</value>
    </something2>
    <something3>
        <other>Var</other>
    </something3>
</Defs>
```

**XPath 1.0**

Any leaf node where node has a textual value. More precisely, it selects any element that doesn't have a child element. And 2nd condition where ancestor-or-self::* contains "value" in its name.

```
/Defs//*[not(*)][ancestor-or-self::*[contains(local-name(),"value")]]
```

**Output**

```
<li>Thing</li>
<value>Foo</value>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, XPath 1.0 #1 produces the output I'm looking for. However the name Thing is a placeholder and actually could be anything, but that's the intended output I'm looking for. I'll include that in my post.

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide all ##1-4

Comment: I have edited my question and hopefully fulfilled points ##1-4. I have also changed Thing1 and Thing2 to better represent what I am asking. Thanks so much for the help thus far.

Comment: I modified the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me realise I had missed important information in my question. I'm sorry for the hassle, I have modified the question again.